# Get first image from google

Tags: javascript, image, google-search, google-search-api

I want to display the first image on google search in my website against a keyword. I would really like some pointers in this direction.

Thank you!

Comment: And is for javascript, not android.

Comment: Request the image with the URL from images (search the words and grab the url edit the "q" parameter) as so:
"https://www.google.com/search?q="+searchImage+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X"
Fetch it with AJAX and the result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See following links:

[Google’s Custom Search API now supports image-only results](http://googlecode.blogspot.in/2012/02/image-results-now-available-from-custom.html)

[Google Image Search API](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide)

Comment: Now is deprecated and in legacy

Comment: 2018 Update: This might help https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/customizingresults